# Как сократить JS-код?

Tags: javascript

Простой код, но блоков может быть много. Как оптимизировать?

```
ch1.onclick = function() {
    if (ch1.checked) { document.getElementById('lab1').disabled = false; }
    else { document.getElementById('lab1').disabled = true; }
};
ch2.onclick = function() {
    if (ch2.checked) { document.getElementById('lab2').disabled = false; }
    else { document.getElementById('lab2').disabled = true; }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function CheckBoxChange(aCheckbox, aLabelId) {
  if (aCheckbox.checked) { 
    document.getElementById(aLabelId).disabled = false; 
  } else { 
    document.getElementById(aLabelId).disabled = true; 
  }
};

ch1.onclick = function() { CheckBoxChange(this, 'lab1'); };
ch2.onclick = function() { CheckBoxChange(this, 'lab2'); };
```

Comment: Можно содержимое функции `CheckBoxChange` сделать одной строкой: `document.getElementById(aLabelId).disabled = !(aCheckbox.checked); `

Comment: @cyadvert точно

Answer (score 4):

объединил предыдущие коменты:

```
function makeCheckBoxChange(aCheckbox, aLabelId) {
   return function () {
     document.getElementById(aLabelId).disabled = !(aCheckbox.checked);
   };
}

ch1.onclick = makeCheckBoxChange(ch1, 'lab1');
ch2.onclick = makeCheckBoxChange(ch2, 'lab2');
```